# regex for javascript pattern match

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm looking for a regex expression or javascript which alerts me when a number is NOT between 48-47 or NOT between 96-105 or IS NOT 110 OR 190 OR 8 OR 13.

thanks for all the help friends !!

Comment: I would strongly urge you to accept an answer to some of your other questions.

Comment: Why would you do this with a regex instead of doing simpler (and faster!) numeric comparisons?

Comment: Regexps are not really meant for this..

Answer (score 5):

Regex is not appropriate for such specific numeric checks.  Just do a few `if` statements to compare the value you're working with to the specific values and ranges you want to exclude.

```
var number = 19;
alert('Number is'+(numberIsValid(number) ? 'valid' : 'not valid'));

    function numberIsValid(number) {
      // test for numeric argument
      if ((number - 0) != number)
        return false;
      // test for specific exclusions
      if (number == 110 || number == 190 || number == 8 || number == 13 || number == 48 || number == 47)
        return false;
      // test for excluded range
      if (number >= 96 && number <= 105)
        return false;
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Boo for implicit conversions.  Rather use `parseInt(number, 10)` and `isNaN`.

Comment: @Eevee why?  "parseInt()" is actually kind-of a pain, because it'll return a valid number from the string "12hello there".  Implicit conversion will not.

Comment: Implicit conversion is more efficient and a much more direct way to test for numeric, there really isn't a compelling reason not to use this pattern.  It isn't considered part of "best practice", IMO, similar to how array literals are more efficient even though there is a more formal way to instantiate an array.

Comment: @Pointy: Relying on weak typing behavior is often wacky and subtle, so I try to avoid it.  But that's a good point.  Could use `Number()`, which ought to work the same as the implicit conversion, though it doesn't seem to be a popular approach.

Comment: Javascript is a weakly typed language.  There's no sense in avoiding that fact because it seems "wacky"; that's the way it is, and that's the way it will stay, so there's no danger in using that to your advantage when you can. :)

Comment: The weak typing is convenient at times, but a construction like `(number - 0) != number` isn't exactly obvious at a glance, especially for a variable called `number`.  :)  You can leave a comment, but an explicit conversion obviates the need for one.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Chris's response above, if you want to see what it would look like, it is kind of a mess.  I wouldn't really recommend you use this.

Just to rephrase: Number may not be 8,13,47,48,96-105,110

```
var num = 10;
if (! /^(8|13|47|48|9[6-9]|10[0-5]|110)$/.test(num)) {
    alert(num);
}
```

Comment: Ugh.  +1 for cobbling it together... I wasn't even going to try.

Answer (score 1):

```
function allowedIntegers(n){
    return !/^([^\d]|8|13|47|48|110|190|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104)$/.test(String(n));
}
```

Comment: Your regex is even uglier than mine :)